# Magnitude of work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

I am a little bit confused on the concept of work. 
By definition, work done by a constant force of magnitude F on a point that moves a displacement s in the direction of the force is W = Fs.
So lets say there is a piece of space junk travelling at 1000m/s with no force acting on it, and suddenly a 1N force with opposite direction exerts on it for 1 second, then during the time period when the force was in effect, F = 1, s = about 999m because the effect of the force is so small compare to the current velocity of the object. I believe that the work done is not 999 joules. Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: *"I believe that the work done is not 999 joules."* Sign aside, can you explain why you don't believe it is 999 joules?

Comment: Why don't you apply the Work-energy theorem to verify that the work performed (actually 999.5 J) equals the change in kinetic energy?

Comment: @BMS I think that if the object moves at 2000m/s with the same mass the work calculated would be 1999, but since work is change in kinetic energy, the same force acting for the same amount of time should done the same amount of work. I missed the sign by the way. please excuse me if i seem to be unclear of other concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply force for a given amount of time, the thing you can compute most easily is the change in momentum, since

$$F \Delta t = m \Delta v$$

(for simplicity I assume that $F$ is constant during $\Delta t$, and that $m$ doesn't change. Which is valid in this case.)

Now you can compute the change in kinetic energy:

$$\begin{align}\Delta E &= \frac12 m (v_f^2 - v_i^2)\\
&= \frac12 m (v_f - v_i)(v_f+v_i)\\
&= \frac12 m (\Delta v )(2 v_i - \Delta v)\\
&= m \Delta v v_i - \frac12 m (\Delta v)^2\\
&= (F \Delta t) v_i -\frac12  \frac{(F \Delta t )^2}{m}\\
\end{align}$$

As you can see, unless you know the size of $m$, you cannot estimate the work done. Basically, a very heavy object will continue at the same speed; the distance covered will be 1000 m, and the first term dominates. The smaller the mass is, the more significant the second term - this will make the work done smaller.

Comment: thanks for the explaination. If i got it correct, the same force acting on object of the same mass for the same amount of time will done different amount of work if the object has different initial velocity, is this true? so if m=1 then the work done is actually 999.5 J in the situation stated?

Comment: Yes that's right on both statements.

Comment: Just to clarify, by common sense, the same force acting on object of the same mass for the same amount of time will done same amount of work because the change in velocity should be the same. is there any explanation for this?

Comment: No that's not true - it also needs to have the same initial velocity $v_i$. Change in velocity is not enough - look more close at the equation: it is the change in the velocity **squared** that counts.